# How do I host a domain I bought on GoDaddy on Media Temple?

Tags: wordpress, godaddy, mediatemple

I bought Media Temple hosting and want to build a Wordpress.org site using a domain I bought on GoDaddy.

**What steps do I need to take to make Media Temple recognize my GoDaddy domain as one that it should host?**

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It belongs on the webmasters site. But in short, you have to point your domain at a media temple IP address, configure media temple to understand that that IP is for serving up your site, etc...

Comment: Whoops, sry about that... What's the webmaster's site?

Answer (score 1):

I think this article on the Media Temple knowledgebase should tell you what you need. http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/5/%28mt%29+Media+Temple%27s+DNS%7B47%7DNameserver+information

Answer (score 0):

Go to the domain controller or DNS management in your godaddy account and set the Name Server (NS) address to point the Name Servers of Media Temple.

Answer (score 0):

This answer applies to the MediaTemple DV servers.  Depending on which hosting service you went with it might be a little different for you.

To have your domain name resolve to your new MT server you need to do 3 things.

1 . Create the domain in Plesk.  You should have gotten an email from MT that has a URL for plesk access for your new hosting.  Log in, click domains then add a new domain.

2 . Add a DNS record to your MT hosting.  Typically this is done at http://ac.mediatemple.net .  Log in. Click on Domains then Add a new domain or service.

3 . Point your new domain to MT's nameservers.  Log in to your Godaddy account, manage domains, edit name servers.  Typically the nameservers will be NS1.MEDIATEMPLE.NET and NS2.MEDIATEMPLE.NET .

Do those steps then give it a while to propagate and you should be up and running.